# Import data to HVE (Finding trending topics using Google Books n-grams data )

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive

I'm doing step by step guide http://aws.amazon.com/articles/5249664154115844

Step :Creating input table

```
hive>
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE english_1grams (
 gram string,
 year int,
 occurrences bigint,
 pages bigint,
 books bigint
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
STORED AS SEQUENCEFILE
LOCATION 's3://datasets.elasticmapreduce/ngrams/books/20090715/eng-all/1gram/';
```

My system build in :ubuntu +(hadoop +hive) not AWS(EC2)
so I changed `LOCATION -> LOCATION 'home/hduser/googlebook'`

folder googlebook obtaine :all file ,i have download at http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/datasetsv2.html
version 2

So i have a issues is when i query

```
hive>SELECT * from ngrams
```

result is 0  ->database no data? What should i do ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not clear with your problem, but the table you create is `english_1grams` but your hql is `select * from ngrams`.

> Here is my step, and I am sure I can see the data.

1. I download the data from the site [google book](http://storage.googleapis.com/books/ngrams/books/googlebooks-eng-all-1gram-20120701-2.gz) and  decompress to my home folder.
2. Enter hive copy data from local to hadoop `dfs -copyFromLocal ${env:HOME}/googlebooks-eng-all-1gram-20120701-2 /user/hive/warehose/googlebook`
3. I create the table

   ```
   create external table english_gram(
       gram string,
       year int,
       page int,
       book int)
       row format delimited
       fields terminated by '\t'
       stored as textfile
       location 'hdfs://ubuntu:9005/user/hive/warehouse/googlebook';
   ```
4. `select * from english_gram;` you will see the data.